# Highlight duplicate values in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, duplicate-data

I'm outputting a list of purchases, and I want to automatically highlight the presence of duplicate orders.

Here's what the array looks like. The first two orders are duplicate orders place by mistake. You'll notice that the orderid for each is different, while the email and userid remain the same. So the duplication will need to match on email and / or userid, but not on orderid.

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'orderid' => string '2009091008261662'
      'email' => string 'john@example.com'
      'userid' => string '53'
array
  1 => 
    array
      'orderid' => string '2009091008261048'
      'email' => string 'john@example.com'
      'userid' => string '53'
array
  2 => 
    array
      'orderid' => string '2009091008262025'
      'email' => string 'fred@example.com'
      'userid' => string '103'
array
  3 => 
    array
      'orderid' => string '2009091008272082'
      'email' => string 'tom@example.com'
      'userid' => string '392'
```

How can I search for duplicate orders from the same person in a given array, in PHP?

I would like to output the above like so:

(pretend its in a table)

**2009091008261662 - john@example.com - 53**

**2009091008261048 - john@example.com - 53**

2009091008262025 - fred@example.com - 103

2009091008272082 - tom@example.com - 392

... so basically just highlight the two ( or more ) duplicates.

Comment: Topically related: [Update column value in each row where the row is identical to another row in the same 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75094492/2943403) contains a better suited answer if you merely want to store a duplicate flag in the row versus printing the indicator of duplicity.

Answer (score 4):

Assumes uniqueness based on `userid` value

```
<?php

$orders = array(
  array(
    'orderid' => '2009091008261662',
    'email' => 'john@example.com',
    'userid' => '53'
  ),
  array(
    'orderid' => '2009091008261048',
    'email' => 'john@example.com',
    'userid' => '53'
  ),
  array(
    'orderid' => '2009091008262025',
    'email' => 'fred@example.com',
    'userid' => '103'
  ),
  array(
    'orderid' => '2009091008272082',
    'email' => 'tom@example.com',
    'userid' => '392'
  ),
  array(
    'orderid' => '2009091008265555',
    'email' => 'john@example.com',
    'userid' => '53'
  )
);

$foundIds = array();
foreach ( $orders as $index => $order )
{
  if ( isset( $foundIds[$order['userid']] ) )
  {
    $orders[$index]['is_dupe'] = true;
    $orders[$foundIds[$order['userid']]]['is_dupe'] = true;
  } else {
    $orders[$index]['is_dupe'] = false;
  }
  $foundIds[$order['userid']] = $index;
}
?>

<style type="text/css">
tr.dupe td {
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

<table>
  <tr><th>orderid</th><th>email</th><th>
  <?php foreach ( $orders as $order ) { ?>
  <tr class="<?php echo $order['is_dupe'] ? 'dupe' : '' ?>">
    <td><?php echo $order['orderid']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $order['email']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $order['userid']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be essentially "invert" the array into an associative one mapping values to keys from the original array:

```
$emails = array();
$userids = array();

foreach($inputarray as $key => $item) {
    if( isset($emails[$item['email']]) || isset($userids[$item['userid']]) ) {
        // This item has a duplicate email or userid as something already looked at!
        // $emails[$item['email']] or $userids[$item['userid']] has the key corresponding to the original location where it was seen.
        // $key has the key corresponding to the duplicate we just found.
    } else {
        $emails[$item['email']] = $key;
        $userids[$item['userid']] = $key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a hash to the inner-array which represents the the array. Just loop through and compare the hashes.

Answer (score 0):

This code works...

```
$array1[0]['orderid'] = '2009091008261662';
$array1[0]['email'] = 'john@example.com';
$array1[0]['userid'] = '53';
$array1[1]['orderid'] = '2009091008261662';
$array1[1]['email'] = 'john@example.com';
$array1[1]['userid'] = '53';
$array1[2]['orderid'] = '2009091008261662';
$array1[2]['email'] = 'john2@example.com';
$array1[2]['userid'] = '53';
$array1[3]['orderid'] = '209091008261662';
$array1[3]['email'] = 'joh3@example.com';
$array1[3]['userid'] = '53';
$array1[4]['orderid'] = '2001008261662';
$array1[4]['email'] = 'john@example.com';
$array1[4]['userid'] = '53';
$array1[5]['orderid'] = '20013344008261662';
$array1[5]['email'] = 'johnddd@example.com';
$array1[5]['userid'] = '53';
$array1[6]['orderid'] = '200133352008261662';
$array1[6]['email'] = 'johsdfgsdn@example.com';
$array1[6]['userid'] = '53';


$unique_array = array(); // Filtered array with no dupes
$email_array = array(); // Hash list
$order_array = array(); // Hash list
foreach($array1 as $i => $row) {

 if (array_key_exists($row['email'], $email_array)) {
  // This is a dupe based on email
  $array1[$i]['duplicate'] = 1;
  $array1[$email_array[$row['email']]]['duplicate'] = 1;
 }

 if (array_key_exists($row['orderid'], $order_array)) {
  // This is a dupe based on email
  $array1[$i]['duplicate'] = 1;
  $array1[$order_array[$row['orderid']]]['duplicate'] = 1;
 }
 $order_array[$row['orderid']] = $i;
 $email_array[$row['email']] = $i;
}
foreach($array1 as $i => $row) {
 if (!empty($row['duplicate'])) {
  echo "<b>" . $row['orderid'] . $row['email'] . "</b>\n";
  unset($row['duplicate']); // reset the array to original form
 } else {
  echo $row['orderid'] . $row['email'] . "\n";
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two passes of the orders array.  But it's really more simple than some have made it out to be:

```
$duplicateUserId = array();

// Mark user ID's with more than one order
foreach ( $orders as $order ) {
    $duplicateUserId[$order['userid']] = isset($duplicateUserId[$order['userid']]);
}

// Output each order
foreach ( $orders as $order ) {
    echo formatOrder($order, $duplicateUserId[$order['userid']]);
}

// Format the output of each order
function formatOrder($order, $isDuplicated) {
    // yadda yadda yadda
}
```

Assuming that $orders looks like

```
$orders = array(
  array(
    'orderid' => '2009091008261662',
    'email' => 'john@example.com',
    'userid' => '53'
  ),
  array(
    'orderid' => '2009091008261048',
    'email' => 'john@example.com',
    'userid' => '53'
  ),
  array(
    'orderid' => '2009091008262025',
    'email' => 'fred@example.com',
    'userid' => '103'
  ),
  array(
    'orderid' => '2009091008272082',
    'email' => 'tom@example.com',
    'userid' => '392'
  ),
  array(
    'orderid' => '2009091008265555',
    'email' => 'john@example.com',
    'userid' => '53'
  )
);
```

Also, it might be best to only match on userId since, presumably, users can change their emails and emails are unique to a single user.

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer:

```
function hasDuplicate($arr,$email) {
  $count = 0;
  foreach ($arr as $row) {
     if ($row['email'] == $email) {
       $count++;
     }
  }
  return ($count >1);
}
```

Comment: -1 for O(n^2) when it could just be O(2n) -> O(n).  Also, you could just return true as soon as $count is not 0 instead of iterating of the whole array.

Comment: I said it was simple not efficient.  Beware of premature optimization. And yes you could return true as soon $count is > 1.  But not 0 as there will always be 1 match.