# Update column value in each row where the row is identical to another row in the same 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates

I have a multi-dimensional array like the following:

```
$arr = [
    ['name' => 'John', 'age' => 10, 'gender' => 'male', 'info' => ''],
    ['name' => 'Jeniffer', 'age' => 12, 'gender' => 'female', 'info' => ''],
    ['name' => 'John', 'age' => 10, 'gender' => 'male', 'info' => '']
];
```

I want to detect whether one of the arrays that it contains is duplicated. If it's a duplicated array, I want to append index of info with "DUPLICATED".

For example, here's what the final result (output) would look like when applying the logic to the original multi-dimensional array:

```
$arr = [
    ['name' => 'John', 'age' => 10, 'gender' => 'male', 'info' => 'DUPLICATED'],
    ['name' => 'Jeniffer', 'age' => 12, 'gender' => 'female', 'info' => ''],
    ['name' => 'John', 'age' => 10, 'gender' => 'male', 'info' => 'DUPLICATED']
];
```

How can I do this?

I have tried using the following code:

```
$uploadData = array_unique($uploadData->toArray(), SORT_REGULAR);
```

…but it only produces a unique array (i.e., it eliminates all duplicates). This is not what I want. I just want the duplicates to be annotated with an indication that they are a duplicate.

Comment: Also, what EXACTLY constitutes a duplicate?

Comment: @mickmackusa they aren't asking if an array has singular duplicated info in it. They're asking if the entire array's content is a duplicate to another one, how to append the word DUPLICATED into all the arrays that contain exactly the same info.

Comment: `how to append the word DUPLICATED into all the arrays that contain exactly the same info.` Isn't that what my answer does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Iterate the input array only one time.
- Create a unique identifier by joining all row values with a delimiting character.
- If the identifier has not yet been encountered, assign a reference variable to the `info` element of that row (but don't update the value).
- If the identifier has been encountered before, update the current row and the reference variable with `DUPLICATED`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NY92d))

```
foreach ($arr as &$row) {
    $compositeKey = implode('_', $row);
    if (isset($info[$compositeKey])) {  // not first occurrence
        $info[$compositeKey] = 'DUPLICATED';  // overwrite reference value
        $row['info'] = 'DUPLICATED'; // update current row's value
    } else {
        $info[$compositeKey] = &$row['info'];  // first occurrence, assign reference
    }
}
var_export($arr);
```